# How to set explicit axis extents for datetime axis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts scatter plot with a datetime x-axis. I want to explicitly set the min and max values for the x-axis, regardless of the chart width.

In the example below, I set `xAxis.min` to be `01/05/2023`, but you can see that the plot renders with `01/04/2023` as the minimum value. It seems this minimum value can vary depending on the width of the plot.

Is there any way that I can set specific start/end values for the axis (and use startOnTick/endOnTick), regardless of the plot width?

```js
let start = "05 Jan 2023 00:00:00 GMT"; // x-axis start
let end = "12 Jan 2023 00:00:00 GMT"; // x-axis end

Highcharts.chart("trendPlot", {
  accessibility: { enabled: false },
  chart: {
    type: "scatter",
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    min: Date.parse(start),
    max: Date.parse(end),
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    labels: {
      format: "{value:%m/%d/%y}",
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  series: [{
    "data": [
      [1672894800000, 1]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```css
#trendPlot {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="trendPlot"></div>
```

Comment: Your dates are not parsed to what you expect from the strings you provide. Check them out with `console.log(new Date(start))`, etc. Check out [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for a format that you can be certain js parses as you expected, in every environment.

Comment: I advised to change the string, not the method (`Date.parse` reference was included because it describes ISO 8601 format - which is the safest bet for all browsers) . The two values in your message are indeed equal, but they may be both wrong or inadequate -- they are **user time zone dependent**, while Highcharts works by default with UTC, and [setting the time zone](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time) to user time zone is a lot of trouble that is best avoided (by using UTC dates)

Comment: @kikon Thanks you. I updated the date format but the issue still occurs. It appears to be due to the `startOnTick` value.

Comment: You're right. Still, controlling the time zone is important. Compare [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tdasf9g/4/) that uses ISO 8601 with the GMT flag set with [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/1tdasf9g/3/) that uses natural language, no GMT, and starts from 4 Jan (at least for users that are east of Greenwich). The second one may also very well fail for users that have their main language set to something other than English.

Comment: Also, I think Highcharts [assumes UTC by default](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC), unless `useUTC` is set to `false`. But I agree, being explicit with the time zone is important.

Answer (score 0):

Put a data as a UNIX time format, timestamp or Date.UTC method for preparing data, explained how to working with [data-compression](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-compression) in Highcharts.

```
  chart: {
    type: "scatter",
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
    labels: {
      format: "{value:%m/%d/%y}",
      enabled: true,
    },
    min: Date.UTC(2019, 5, 18),
    max: Date.UTC(2019, 5, 20),
  },
  series: [{
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 5, 18),
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2019, 5, 18), 1],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 5, 18), 3],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 5, 20), 5],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 5, 21), 1]
    ]
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oq9Luxey/

Comment: Thanks, but [.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) does provide a Unix timestamp. If I modify your example somewhat, this still occurs even using `Date.UTC`. Just shrink and expand the window in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/c84z1wbn/) and you'll see the start date sometimes change to a value outside of the provided `min`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I just meant that the two formats are recognisable by the UNIX way of writing time. About the case, occurs because [startOnTick](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick) in your [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r9fbx30q/) force tick to start on available tick which changes when the size changed.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to set the start tick to always use a specific value? i.e., so in my example it's always 01/05/2023, regardless of chart width?

Comment: You can use [xAxis.tickPositions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions) to set positions, also it's possible to adjust way how to xaxis labels look when you resize width by [responsive](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive), [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r9fbx30q/1/).